# What is 中 after a verb?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

In the examples below what does 中 stand for and how is it pronounced?

> 15日は海からの強い風が吹きつける**中**、およそ２０人の男たちが、運河に架かる橋の欄干から次々と水の中に飛び込みました。

and

> オホーツク海の流氷が南下する**中**、北海道紋別市の流氷観光船「ガリンコ号」が今シーズン初めて流氷の中を航行し、観光客が雄大な景色を楽しみました。

Is 中 attached to the verb (I thought it can be attached like this only to nouns), or is it separate from it (if so why isn't there の between them) or is something else the case here?

Answer (score 6):

The pronunciation is "naka（なか）," "中{なか}."

"中{なか}" = during, while or "・・・in blowing strong wind", "・・・in advancing southwards".

> 強い風が吹きつける中
> = 「強い風が吹きつける」＋「中=during or while」
> = 強い風が吹きつける最中

Comment: Probably should be marked as answer. By the way, how does 中 compare to ～ている(時に)? The former is shorter as a noun phrase + particle, but I also see 中 at the end of sentences, where there isn't much difference.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned already, 中 also means "during or while" and pronounciation is "naka".

However, 中 sometimes includes Contradictory conjunction nuance.
So, the first exapmle means that 20 mens dived to sea **though** or **despite of** strong wind.

～ている(時に) doesn't have such a nuance. It just means while or during.

The second example's 中 is almost same as "while" (not including contradictory conjuction nuance)